# Read and Write to File at the same time

Tags: c#, file

for an application that uses a File as some sort of global storage for device reservations in a firm I need a way to read and write to a file (or lock a file, read from it, write to it, and unlock it). A little code snippet will shot what I mean:

```
FileStream in = new FileStream("storage.bin", FileMode.Open);
//read the file
in.Close();

//!!!!!
//here is the critical section since between reading and writing, there shouldnt
//be a way for another process to access and lock the file, but there is the chance
//because the in stream is closed
//!!!!!
FileStream out = new FileStream("storage.bin", FileMode.Create);
//write data to file
out.Close();
```

this should get something like this

```
LockFile("storage.bin");
//read from it...
//OVERwrite it....
UnlockFile("storage.bin");
```

the method should be absolute safe, since the program should run on 2000 devices at the same time

Comment: to overcome the issue with the critical section, so ensure that the file doesnt get locked after closing the instream

Comment: Ultimately it will turn by turn, instead reading and writing at once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply holding a `FileStream` open with exclusive (not shared) access will prevent other processes from accessing the file. This is the default when opening a file for read/write access.

You can 'overwrite' a file that you currently hold open by truncating it.

So:

```
using (var file = File.Open("storage.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    // read from the file

    file.SetLength(0); // truncate the file

    // write to the file
}
```

> the method should be absolute safe, since the program should run on 2000 devices at the same time

Depending on how often you're writing to the file, this could become a chokepoint. You probably want to test this to see how scalable it is.

In addition, if one of the processes tries to operate on the file at the same time as another one, an `IOException` will be thrown. There isn't really a way to 'wait' on a file, so you probably want to coordinate file access in a more orderly fashion.

Comment: k this helped me, and im waiting on a file in a thread with a loop and a try catch inside, it just opens it until it gets available, which works for me, and didnt know I can write and read in a single filestream, this was basically what I was looking for, will accept in 2 min

Answer (score 3):

You need a single stream, opened for both reading and writing.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(
      @"c:\words.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
      FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

Alternatively you can also try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\words.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\words.txt", text + "DERP");
    }
```

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.71).aspx

```
FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

You need to pass in a FileShare enumeration value of None to open on the FileStream constructor overloads:

```
fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Juan Luis\Desktop\corte.txt", FileMode.Open, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: The combination of `ReadAllText`/`WriteAllText` will have the same problem (another process can access the file in between). A single `FileStream` works, though.

Comment: Have edited my comment, kindly have a look at the last 2 approaches, hope it will help. It will produce a "The specified file is in use" error message when someone try to open it with another application.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing this helper class to do this:

```
public static class FileHelper
{
    public static void ReplaceFileContents(string fileName, Func<String, string> replacementFunction)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(
                fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
            string currentContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var newContents = replacementFunction(currentContents);
            fileStream.SetLength(0);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            writer.Write(newContents);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

which allows you to pass a function that will take the existing contents and generate new contents and ensure the file is not read or modified by anything else whilst this change is happening

Comment: Am I wrong or 1. Is there a problem that streamReader is not disposed cleanly, and 2. write is not disposed in case of an error? Are 3 using statements needed here?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for [FileStream.Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock) and [FileStream.Unlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.unlock)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use the [FileShare.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) flag in the overloaded Open method.

```
file = File.Open("storage.bin", FileMode.Open, FileShare.None);
```