# How to write and read to file reactively in the same time

Tags: java

Someone knows way to write and read from file (xml, json) in java where 
java object will be able to store in file in reactive way.

For now I use 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator` to write objects to json file.

For reading from file I'm using 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser`

but I'm not able to write and read from file in the same time.
I don't want to have many open/close file descriptor operations.

It's way to do it in java?

My business scenario:

I read records from one big file ( more then couple of GB) and I need to create relations between records.
Records in input file unfortunetlly are not sorted and it's imposible to write to sort file when all records are in perfect order.

I iterate over input file and find `parent record` and want to write the record to second file when I was created realations between records.

In second step I want to write `child record` but I need to iterate over `record relations file` (read file operation with open write descriptor) and I need to find find `parent record` for my `child record` and update that parent record when I fill `child structure` where insert `child_1 element` example structure used by me right now:

```
{
"parent_1": {
...
childs: [{
"child_1": { ... } 
}]
}
}
```

Comment: Do you need to actually read for changes? Most programs just read the file once, store it in memory, edit the in-memory content, then when it's modified save it

Comment: @zack6849 I cannot store all my records in memory because it will produce out of memory (my team make that tests and it's real scenario).

Comment: is it possible to change the application to NOT be flatfile based? this seems like exactly the sort of thing you'd want a database or key value store for

Answer (score 0):

The description of your problem is not very clear, we don't know *why* you want to do that and *what you want to achieve*. But i'll have a try:

If you try to do something like React.js does in JavaScript, you'd need your program to monitor if the file has changed and *react* to that by updating the corresponding object. But this won't be very performant (nor make much sense) - maybe just using **static fields** in you object's class to maintain state between instances would do the trick? If that applies to your scenario at all...

Comment: Storing data in memory it is not an option. I use small object amout the objects is to hight to store them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would load and save a file in its entirety with their file modification times (or a running version number/UUID in the json).

For multiple files, and possibly multiple accesses to the same file one needs a managing class.

The class [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) is usefull for loading/saving.

```
Path path = Paths.get("...");
FileTime t = Files.getLastModified(path);
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
FileTime tcheck = Files.getLastModified(path);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = ...
```

In this way access is as atomic/momentarily as possible.

Ideally one could use `FileLock.lock()`, but that is more for random-access files,
file channels, especially with buffers. For instance if the json files were really huge.
However then the json format is inadequate itself.

Comment: I heared about c# file streams but I didn't found any implementation in java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627276/read-and-write-to-file-at-the-same-time

Comment: Look at Channel. One can open a Channel immediately, or do a RandomAccessFile.getChannel. A Channel one can lock. _I hope I remember correctly._ Locking a file for a longer time is not that ideal. One mechanism is to create a .lock file to signal to the software for exclusivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for my case will be:

- read parent record and find for him all child records (store in memory) and after
  reaching end-of-file flush my parent record + child records to `relations_file`
- for reading and writing best approach will be use of FileChannel